# Combine multiple svn diff into one big file

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, git-diff

I want to combine multiple 'diff' svn files, into one big one, all of which are non-sequential.

I believe i need to convert the svn diff files to a new format where some other tool can combine them. I do not want to use merge i just want a unified diff of multiple non-sequential commits.

```
svn diff -c 1002 > diff2.txt
svn diff -c 1001 > diff1.txt
```

The above code produces 2 good 'svn diff files'. How would I combine them?
I see that svn diff has a '--git' optinon so i am generating a diff file that is compatible with git. How would i take multiple .gittdiff files and combine them to get a unified git file.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.git

Note: I am on windows, so i need a windows solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could try `combinediff` that comes with [`patchutils`](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Patchutils). You can easily run it in Bash via [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux). See [Windows Subsystem for Linux Installation Guide for Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).

[image]

Here is an example:

```
sudo apt-get install patchutils
svn diff -c100001 https://svn.example.com/MyRepo/ > 1.diff
svn diff -c100002 https://svn.example.com/MyRepo/ > 2.diff
combinediff 1.diff 2.diff > out.diff
```

Note that I think that you will need to adjust the command line to meet your requirements.

Comment: I am not on linux, how would I do that on windows, install patchutils on windows?

Comment: @ionescu, for native Windows tools install MSYS2 - same package names: "pacman -S diffutils patch patchutils".

Comment: @kxr the answer already shows how to install Linux tools on Windows without having to deal with msys2.

Comment: @bahrep yes it does. But in the given answer you need to deal with wsl2 (that could mean changing bios options, i.e. Virtual Machine Platform a subset of hyper-v). So an alternative given by kxr is always good to know